# How does one code data from a different (test) file vs all the data in one file?

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

All examples I've ever come across always conveniently have data in one file to show how train_test_split works (or any model really). But quite often the training data and testing data are two separate files.
So, I made a ultra-basic logistic regression train file and test file consisting of two columns, 'age', 'insurance'. And naming the df's df_train, df_test.

I realize df_test hasn't been trained, hence the error but...isn't that the point?
I know `model.predict(X_test)` doesn't throw an error, but that is based on the training data not the test data.

Word of warning, this is what happens when you're old and trying to learn new things. Don't get old.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['age']],df.insurance,test_size=0.1)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.predict(df_test)
```

Thanks,

Old fart

Answer (score 0):

As  you stated :

> train file and test file consisting of two columns, 'age',
>   'insurance'.

So if test files contains both age and insurance columns and used as it is, the predict function will not work because of mis-match of input between training and prediction.
Also model.predict expect the independent variable only(in your case its age) in below format :

predict(self, X)[source]¶

```
Predict class labels for samples in X.
Parameters: 

X : array_like or sparse matrix, shape (n_samples, n_features)

    Samples.
```

Now coming to the modification :

```
model.predict(df_test["age"].values)
```

**Edit** : Try this :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = df["age"].values
y = df["insurance"].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.1)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.predict([list(df_test["age"].values)])
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion and got: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. So, I attempted to fix that issue with, ```x_train= x_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train= y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 1)```. Which gave another error. ''DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'"

Comment: Have edited the post, just try the edited version and you will get the output.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Still getting an error, `Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`. And that error is even AFTER I input what should have corrected it, `X_train= X_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train= y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 1)`. I put that piece before model.fit, and it still says it's a 1D array.

Comment: Error: X has 20 features per sample; expecting 1. I appreciate your persistence. I keep thinking this shouldn't be that difficult. maybe my simple example is too simple? i.e. could it use an additional column of features?

Comment: Yes additional column of Features can be used while prediction.